# Why does pandas df.values convert tuple into strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with 4000 over data, in which each cells contains a tuple which holds a specific coordinated. I will like to convert it to a numpy array to work with. I use pandas to convert it into a DataFrame before calling `df.values`. However after calling `df.values`, the tuple becomes a string `"(x,y)"`, instead. Is it possible to prevent this happening? Thank you.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(sample_data)
    array = df.values
```

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is from csv always get tuples as strings.

So need convert them:

```
import ast

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Or if all columns are tuples:

```
df = df.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: this also worked for me. At OP - could you please add what does ast do?

Comment: @Led - `st.literal_eval` is used in python for convert strings repr to python object, it means if string `'{"a":5}'` is converted to dict `{'a':5}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you read the file from local path ?
My answer is use eval to change the string:

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.apply(eval))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change the data type after reading the csv:

```
df['col'].apply(tuple)
```